# ¿Cuál es la diferencia si los using están adentro o afuera del namespace?

Tags: c#

¿Existe alguna diferencia técnica concreta en entre hacer esto…

```
using OtraLibreria;
namespace Libreria {
  class MiClase {
     /// mas código aqui
  }
}
```

y esto otro?

```
namespace Libreria {
  using OtraLibreria;
  class MiClase {
     /// mas código aqui
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Respuesta original de [Charlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18529/charlie) en [Should 'using' statements be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151560/186133)

Sí hay una ligera diferencia entre los dos. Imagina que tienes el siguiente código en `File1.cs`:

```
// File1.cs
using System;
namespace Externo.Interno
{
    class Foo
    {
        static void Bar()
        {
            double d = Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora imagina que alguien añade otro archivo `File2.cs` que se ve así al proyecto:

```
// File2.cs
namespace Externo
{
    class Math
    {
    }
}
```

El compilador busca `Externo` antes de mirar los `using` fuera del namespace, así que encuentra `Externo.Math` en lugar de `System.Math`. Desafortunadamente (o quizas afortunadamente), `Externo.Math` no tiene ningún miembro llamado `PI` , así que `File1.cs` no compila.

Esto cambia si pones el `using` dentro del namespace de la siguiente manera:

```
// File1b.cs
namespace Externo.Interno
{
    using System;
    class Foo
    {
        static void Bar()
        {
            double d = Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora el compilador busca en `System` antes de `Externo`, encuentra `System.Math` y todo funciona.

Algunos argumentarían que `Math` puede ser un mal nombre para una clase definida por el usuario ya que ya existe una en `System` pero el punto es que sí hay una diferencia y afecta la mantenibilidad del código.

También es interesante notar que es lo que pasa si es que `Foo` está en el namespace `Externo` en lugar de `Externo.Interno`. En ese caso añadir `Externo.Math` en File2 hace que no compile sin importar donde vaya el `using`. Esto significa que el compilador busca el namespace más interno antes de buscar dentro de cualquier `using`.

Answer (score 3):

La diferencia esta en que puedes reducir el largo de la inclusión de los espacios de nombres anidados. Por ejemplo:

```
namespace A
{
    using B; // using A.B
    using C; // using A.C
}
```

Si lo tuvieras a nivel global, por fuera del espacio de nombres, afectaría a todos los espacios de nombres que están dentro de ese archivo. Ejemplo:

```
using X;

namespace A
{
    // Acá puedo hacer uso de X
}

namespace B
{
    // Acá tambien puedo hacer uso de X pero no existe la necesidad
}
```

Para mas información breve sobre el tema, lee esto: [using (Directiva)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sf0df423.aspx#Anchor_1)

Answer (score 2):

Otro punto a tener en cuenta es que una directiva `using` dentro de un bloque `namespace` es local a ese bloque y reemplaza las definiciones externas.

Por ejemplo, supón que tienes definidas las clases `A.MiClase`, `B.MiClase` y `C.MiClase`. Entonces:

```
using A;

//Aquí "MiClase" es "A.MiClase"

namespace X
{
    using B;
    //Aquí "MiClase" es "B.MiClase"
}

namespace Y
{
    using C;
    //Aquí "MiClase" es "C.MiClase"

    namespace Z
    {
        using A;
        //Aquí "MiClase" es de nuevo "A.MiClase"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Segun recuerdo, si ponemos los using dentro del namespace,cargará el ensamblado referenciado sólo cuando éste es llamado. Es decir, cuando la clase que lo utiliza se carga y se lanza.

Al poner los using fuera del namespace, se cargará el ensamblado al cargar el ensamblado principal.
Esto es muy importante en cuanto a rendimiento y consumo de memoria.